# How to save the results including set variables from the stored procedure into the table automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
--Drop the procedure if exists
drop proc if exists [Sp_TestA]

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_TestA]
    (@P1 AS VARCHAR(50),
     @P2 AS VARCHAR(50),
     @P3 AS VARCHAR(50),
     @P4 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT @P1 AS Col1, @P2 AS Col2, @P3 AS Col3, @p4 AS Col4

    DECLARE @col5 VARCHAR(50)
    SET @col5 = 'test'

    SELECT @col5 AS 'test'
END

--To save the results of procedure into a table automatically
Declare @TblRtRcs TABLE
                  (
                      Col1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                      Col2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                      Col3 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                      Col4 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                  );

INSERT INTO @TblRtRcs(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
    EXEC [dbo].[Sp_TestA] @p1 = '5' , @p2 ='5', @p3 ='51', @p4 = '22'

SELECT * 
FROM @TblRtRcs;
```

Comment: when you run the above procedure it says "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the note

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure is returning two datasets then insert statement will get failed. Insert into @table
Execute SP_...
Allows only one dataset to get insert into temp table.
You can do an hack - you can Union 2 data set and then insert into temp table. Using some custom column you can the separate the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the support . I got your point.But how do we do that ? Because once we execute the procedure we will get col1, col2, col3, col4 and test output. How do we break the output here ? Such that col1,col2,col3 and col4 goes to table_1 and test to the table_2 ?

Comment: Any other method or support for the mentioned issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
--Drop the procedure if exists
drop proc if exists [Sp_TestA]
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_TestA]
(@P1 AS VARCHAR(50)
,@P2 AS VARCHAR(50)
,@P3 AS VARCHAR(50)
,@P4 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
as begin

--Declare the variable type
declare @col5 varchar(50)
set @col5 = 'test'

--Selecting the required columns as output
SELECT @P1 AS Col1,@P2 AS Col2,@P3 AS Col3, @p4 AS Col4,@col5 
END

--Steps to insert the results into procedure
--1. Declare the table variables
Declare @TblRtRcs TABLE
(Col1 VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL
,Col2 VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL
,Col3 VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL
,Col4 VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL
,Col5 VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL);

--2. Insert the values automatically to the table
INSERT INTO @TblRtRcs(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,col5)

--3. Execute the procedure
exec [dbo].[Sp_TestA] @p1 = '5' , @p2 ='5', @p3 ='51', @p4 = '22'

--4. Verify the output of the table
SELECT * FROM @TblRtRcs;
```